# I thorougly enjoy _____

Tags: meaning, word-choice, british-english

Does thoroughly fit well in this sentence? Is it appropriate to use it in a formal sentence?

Comment: It is impossible to say, because you have not given us the full context, and because you have not identified what your actual question or concern is— why do you think it *wouldn't* be appropriate? Please take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and read through the  [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on how to use this site. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) may also be of interest.

Comment: @choster my concern is about putting thoroughly and enjoy next to each. I didn't think context was necessary, since my question is specifically about the term "thoroughly enjoy". I am not sure whether this structure is grammatically correct or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly appropriate. 'I thoroughly enjoy the work I do' is lucid English of the highest register.